# How to handle dynamic decorators in python easily?

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

Suppose I got the following setup (simplified):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit, send

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/namespaceOne')
def test_connectOne():
    print('new connection')

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/namespaceTwo')
def test_connectTwo():
    print('new connection')

if __name__ == '__main__':
socketio.run(app)
```

I would now like to move the two functions `test_connectOne` and `test_ConnectTwo` into separate modules. I was thinking about creating two classes for each module and making the functions static like so:

```
class ModuleOne (object):

    @staticmethod
    @socketio.on('connect', namespace='/namespaceOne')
    def test_One():
        print('new connection')
```

But with this I'm running into trouble. I would now have to somehow get the socketio object into the class (e.g. by a simple setter in combination with a static variable). But I guess the annotation `socketio.on()` will trigger right when the module `ModuleOne` is imported somewhere else before I can set any variables.

How can I solve this situation? (I'm open to solutions which go into a completely different directions too.)

Comment: No, decorators are looked up as globals when used as method decorators too; the decorator is looked up whet the `test_One()` method is being defined. I would *not* put your functions in a class, even as static methods. There is simply no additional advantage to it and only serves to complicate your code here. Put the views in actual separate module files instead.

Comment: But how will I get the socketio object into these modules in a clean way?

Comment: You can import it; in your main module import your modules with views *after* the `socketio` object has been defined, and the modules with views can then use `from mainmodule import socketio`.

Comment: See https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/patterns/packages/ as well, the section on Circular Imports.

Comment: Hm sounds still quite complicated/not very pretty. In the end leaving everything as it is seems to be cleanest to me so far. Is there no possibility to manually call the decorators? E.g. socketio.on(test_One, 'connect', namespace='/namespaceOne'); I could unfortunately not find any information about that...

Comment: Decorators are just functions; `@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/namespaceOne')(test_One)` would work.

Comment: Okay. That is kind of awesome. It worked without the leading @. This allows me to separate the functions (e.g. test_One) from having defined on which functions socketio has to listen i.e. put these two concerns in seperate files/modules. This was really helpful. What should I do with this question as its now solved without any answer given?

Comment: I've summarised my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Import the `socketio` object into the separate module you put the views in. As long as you then import that module *after* creating the `socketio` object things work. So in your `main` module you have:

   ```
   from flask import Flask
   from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit, send

   app = Flask(__name__)
   socketio = SocketIO(app)

   import socket_views

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       socketio.run(app)
   ```

   and in `socket_views.py` you have:

   ```
   from main import socketio

   @socketio.on('connect', namespace='/namespaceOne')
   def test_connectOne():
       print('new connection')

   @socketio.on('connect', namespace='/namespaceTwo')
   def test_connectTwo():
       print('new connection')
   ```

   See the [Larger Application](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/patterns/packages/) chapter of the Flask documentation; specifically the Circular Imports section.
2. Apply the `@socketio.on()` decorator 'manually'; the `@expression` syntax is just syntactic sugar to apply a callable to a function. Since the `@socketio.on()` decorator only *registers* you can simply put your views as regular, un-decorated functions in the separate module then register them after importing with:

   ```
   from socket_views import test_connectOne, test_connectTwo

   socketio.on('connect', namespace='/namespaceOne')(test_connectOne)
   socketio.on('connect', namespace='/namespaceTwo')(test_connectTwo)
   ```